# Store languages for a model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

Here is the context : I have `Users` and I want to store what `languages` they speak.

How should I do this ? Create a `Languages` table with association `has_many` for `Users` ? Store it as a hstore in a languages User's column ?

Also, I'm using `simple-form`, I would like to populate a select (`:multiple` because a `User` can speak multiple languages) with all the languages, any idea how to achieve that ? Should I create a constant with all the languages ? Maybe a gem that accomplishes that ?

I did my research but couldn't find anything that fits this need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a basic M:M relation between `User` and `Language` (which is thoroughly described in the [Active Record Associations](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html) guide).

How about a `User` model like:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_languages
  has_many :languages, through: :user_languages
end
```

And a `Language` model like:

```
class Language < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :user_languages
  has_many :users, through: :user_languages
end
```

And a `UserLanguage` model like:

```
class UserLanguage < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :language
end
```

I imagine you would seed your `languages` table.

Comment: That's sounds right to me ! I will go with that then !

That will allow me to easily create a simple_form select populated with all the languages already.

Thanks for your help !